# Why is the following php code not working?

Tags: php, web

The error says Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE on line 11
I have used same code before also and it is working fine there

```
class connection{

// variables for cms login

var $admin_name1 = "name";
var $admin_passwd1 = "passwd";
// variable to recieve data from form 

var rename;    //********** this line is giving error
var repasswd;

function cms_login()
{
if(($this->rename == $this->admin_name1) && ($this->repasswd == $this->admin_passwd1)){ // access granted 
echo 'Access granted<br>';
echo 'Please wait while you are being redirected';
session_start();
$_SESSION['piratica']="active";
$redirect = "Location: landing.php";
echo header($redirect);
}
else { // access denied
echo 'WARNING  !!';
echo '<br>Wrong login details.';

}

} // function cms_login ends here 


} // class connection ends here
```

Comment: Please review the [PHP manual on class declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).  The `var` keyword of PHP4 is long out of date and no longer used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `$` signs in front of your variable names.

```
var $rename;    //********** this line is giving error
var $repasswd;
```

Answer (score 0):

all variables in php start with $

you forgot to add for rename and repasswd variables